# JSONP retrieving JSON

Tags: jquery, json, cross-domain, jsonp

I have read all kinds of threads on this subject and I cannot get this to work.

I am using Jquery 1.8.3 - some threads neglect to mention which version :-)

Here is a sample of the JSON:

```
{
"glossary": {
    "title": "example glossary",
    "GlossDiv": {
        "title": "S",
        "GlossList": {
            "GlossEntry": {
                "ID": "SGML",
                "SortAs": "SGML",
                "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                "Acronym": "SGML",
                "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                "GlossDef": {
                    "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                    "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                },
                "GlossSee": "markup"
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Under the response tab within Firebug, I can see the JSON - excellent, right? NO

Under the console tab, I see the error "invalid label"

If I change the JSON to be enclosed between two brackets "[]", which has no error under the console, but my error function returns the "jqueryNNNNN... was not called" error.

I have tried the data: {} and callback: "mHandler" solutions that have been offered, but nothing is working. I am going from one error to another.

With that said, I do not believe that my code is at fault because I tried a simple getJSON example that allowed me to retrieve these flicker images:

```
$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?",
{
tags: "dogs",
tagmode: "any",
format: "json"
},
function(data) {
$.each(data.items, function(i,item){
  $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#images");
  if ( i == 3 ) return false;
});
});
```

This worked just fine and under the response tab in firebug, I noticed a jquery function with a long number:

```
jQuery11010762139772876748_1371762511442({
    "title": "Recent Uploads tagged dogs",
    "link": "http://www.flickr.com/photos/tags/dogs/",
    "description": "",
    "modified": "2013-06-20T20:44:00Z",
    "generator": "http://www.flickr.com/",
    "items": [
```

This has lead me to believe that maybe the server that I am calling is not configured correctly.

How can this be done on an IIS or .NET server?

This is the current state of the javascript:

```
var mFATimeO = function(){
$.ajaxSetup({
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    crossDomain: true,
    async: false,
    contentType: "application/jsonp; charset=UTF-8",
    data: "[{'glossary':{'GlossEntry':{}}}]",
    dataType: "jsonp json text",
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
      xhr.overrideMimeType("application/jsonp; charset=UTF-8");
    },
    headers: {
        "Authorization": mBaseSixtyFourVar
    },
    url: mFAXferObj.mUrl
});

$.ajax({ 
    success: function(data){
        $("#mResponse").html($.parseJSON(data));
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $("#mResponse").html("xhr.readyState: "+xhr.readyState+", textStatus: "+textStatus+", errorThrown: "+errorThrown+", xhr.responseText: "+$.parseJSON(xhr.responseText));
    }
});
}
```

One other note, the xhr.responseText is always returning null - how can that be, when I see the data under the response tab within firebug?

Also, please confirm that I am on the correct track.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `jQuery11010762139772876748_1371762511442({...})` is EXACTLY what you want it to do. You cannot POST as JSONP, and JSONP cannot be `async: false`.

Comment: Are you getting an error or something?  This seems to work fine to me: http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/4HgPS/

Comment: Yes, the flicker example does work and that is my point. Try reaching a JSON file with the same data as the above glossary JSON. Let me know if it will work for you

Comment: As far as the cannot post with JSONP comment, there is actually a post on this site that said I had to POST and GET would not work, which one is it?